# Interactive time-series based on x-y location on map with hvplot

Tags: holoviews, hvplot, datashader, geoviews

When I have a very large xarray.DataArray `da` with only two dimensions (`x` and `y`) I normally plot using something like:

```py
da.hvplot(x="x", y="y", rasterize=True)
```

Now, if I have a DataArray with three dimensions (`x`, `y` and `time`), I would like to still plot a map as above (say choosing a `time` value), but also click on a map location (that is, select `x` and `y` values) and have all the `time` values for that location displayed in a separate plot.

Is this possible?

I haven't found any `hvplot` example that even remotely relates to this, it seems all plots settings need to be actively selected from a drop-down menu in a widget.